# Angular Directives and ng-repeat for Lists; Doesn't Inherit Parent Class

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, listitem

I'm trying to wrap a standard list item format in an Angular directive, and then use it with ng-repeat inside various list types. The problem is, the directive seems to lose the class of the parent, so the list doesn't render the way it should. Here's an example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked affix">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <my-list-item item="item"></my-list-item>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Renders exactly like:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <my-list-item item="item"></my-list-item>
  </div>
</ul>
```

So, both of these renders exactly the same, neither the way I want them to. How do I make my list item directive aware of its parent's class?

Edit:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked affix">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <my-list-item item="item"></my-list-item>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `my-list-item` directive looks something like this:

```
<a class="myClass" href="{{item.target}}"><span ng-bind-html="item.text"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` isn't a valid child of `<ul>`  in the first place. Really the only valid child is `<li>`

The bootstrap css won't expect it either. Use markup that matches bootstrap suggested markup and apply any appropriate classes that are used in the docs.

As for what gets rendered in `<my-list-item>` you would need to show what that html looks like if it is also problematic

Reference [W3C <UL> Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html)

> Permitted contents
>
> zero or more li elements

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying. I've updated things, but they're still not rendering the way I'd expect. I've updated my question with the new code and the contents of the directive.

Comment: Without an html/css demo that replicates the issue it is hard to know first what `not rendered the way I expect` means...or what to do to resolve it

Comment: Okay, I think this illustrates the problem I'm having:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MSedqw6OAqbQfSmaOrzU?p=preview

Comment: Still producing markup that doesn't match bootstrap css by keeping your `<list-item>` in place.. Add `replace:true,` to directive so `<a>` is direct child of `<li>` then inspect the css rules that appy in browser dev tools to better understand why you see what you see

Comment: ````replace: true```` did it...thank you! I think I need to understand directive better...I get what was going wrong on the CSS level, I just didn't know how to get the directive to do what I wanted. Thanks!